# LinkedIn API: Is it possible to have more than one access token for a user active at the same time?

Tags: token, linkedin-api

I'm developing an integration with LinkedIn for my company, and I'm noticing this behavior when switching between different development environments:

1. I have an active LinkedIn account on EnvA
2. I authorize the same LinkedIn account on EnvB
3. The account on EnvA is immediately denied on all API requests with an error of "Unable to verify access token"

So it seems like there can only be one active access token per LinkedIn user at one time? Is it correct behavior for an existing access token to become invalid upon generation of a new one, even if the other access token is on a different domain?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a new access token for a user invalidates any existing tokens.  You can only have one functional token per app per user at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!